# Hessian of the loss of a linear neural network with respect to a weight matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, quadratics, neural-networks, hessian-matrix

Let $L$ be the loss of a linear neural network:

$$L = \Sigma_j \lVert y_j - W_N\dots W_1 W_0x_j\rVert^2$$

what is $\nabla^2_{W_i}L$, the second derivative of $L$ with respect to $W_i$  for all $i$?

I have no real problem getting the first derivative, the problem happens when I need to take the second derivative, as it means getting the derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix. I've been reading [Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047198633X) which suggests you instead solve for $\nabla^2_{vec W_i}$, but I got pretty lost in the weeds of all of the proofs and am trying to get a handle on it by following the derivation for the linear network case.

Comment: The question is not clear in its current form. What are the activation functions? $W_i$ are matrices of fully connected layers? What is $\nabla^2$ (some "square" of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_i}$, or Frobenius norm of this matrix, or some tensor of second-order derivatives, or something else)? Last but not least: what did you try?

Comment: It's a linear network, so there are no activation functions. $W_i$ have no constraints and are weight matrices of fully connected layers. $\nabla_W^2$ is the second derivative of the loss with respect to the weight matrix $W_i$.

The first derivative poses no real problem: $\nabla_{W_0} = W_0 (\Sigma_{y:x} - W_1W_0\Sigma_{x:x})$ with $\Sigma_{a:b} = \Sigma_j a_jb_j^T$ for a 2 layer network example - but the problem happens when I tried to take the derivative of this function with respect to a matrix. Reading Magnus/Neudecker's book suggests I try $vec$, but I honestly got super lost.

Comment: Apart of the fact that composing more then $2$ linear layers seems to be quite meaningless (the result is a linear function anyway), what is the shape of the resulting tensor $\nabla^2_{W}$? If $W_i$ has shape $(m,n)$, then this $\nabla^2_{W}$ is something of shape $(m,n,m,n)$?

Comment: @peterFranek - depending on if you use the $vec$ operator or not then $\nabla_W^2$ would be either $(mn, mn)$ or some permutation of $(m, n, m, n)$. I am studying the dynamics of how the weight matrices change over time. A linear network is a good *dynamical* approximation to a non-linear network, even if it isn't a good representational one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convenience, let's introduce the partial product matrices
$$\eqalign{
P_{(i...j)} &= \prod_{k=i}^j W_k &= W_iW_{i-1}...W_j \cr
A &= P_{(N...0)} \cr
B_k &= P_{(N...k+1)} \cr
C_k &= P_{(k-1...0)} &\implies A = B_kW_kC_k \cr
}$$
Let's also use the product notation (:) for the trace, e.g.
$$B:C={\rm tr}(B^TC)$$
Now we can write the loss function (ignoring the $j$ subscripts) as
$$L=(Ax-y):(Ax-y)$$
and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
dL
 &= 2(Ax-y):dA\,x \cr
 &= 2(Ax-y)x^T:B_k\,dW_k\,C_k \cr
 &= 2B_k^T(Ax-y)x^TC_k^T:dW_k \cr
G_k = \frac{\partial L}{\partial W_k}
 &= 2B_k^T(Ax-y)x^TC_k^T \cr
}$$
The Hessian is the gradient of $G_k$, so let's start with the differential, and note that at this stage, the only term which contains $W_k$ is $A$ 
$$\eqalign{
dG_k
 &= 2B_k^T\,dA\,xx^TC_k^T \cr
 &= 2B_k^TB_k\,dW_k\,C_kxx^TC_k^T \cr
}$$
But how do you pull the $dW_k$ term out of the middle of a matrix product? That is where vectorization comes in
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dG_k) &= 2(C_kxx^TC_k^T\otimes B_k^TB_k)\,{\rm vec}(dW_k) \cr
H_k = \frac{\partial{\rm vec}(G_k)}{\partial{\rm vec}(W_k)} &= 2C_kxx^TC_k^T\otimes B_k^TB_k\cr
\cr
}$$
If you're willing to allow a tensor solution, then consider the 4th order isotropic tensor ${\mathcal E}$ with components
$$\eqalign{{\mathcal E}_{ijkm} = \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jm} \cr}$$
This tensor allows matrix products to be rearranged, in exactly the way we require
$$\eqalign{
AXB = A{\mathcal E}B^T:X\cr
}$$
Applying this to the differential
$$\eqalign{
dG_k
 &= 2B_k^TB_k\,dW_k\,C_kxx^TC_k^T \cr
 &= 2B_k^TB_k\,{\mathcal E}\,C_kxx^TC_k^T:dW_k \cr
{\mathcal H}_k = \frac{\partial G_k}{\partial W_k}
 &= 2B_k^TB_k\,{\mathcal E}\,C_kxx^TC_k^T \cr
}$$
So the Hessian is itself, a 4th order tensor.

Note the similarity to the vectorized solution. The ${\mathcal E}$ has replaced the $\otimes$ symbol and the factors have swapped sides, but other than that it's the same solution.

Finally, you'll need to slap a $j$-subscript onto $({\mathcal H},G,L,x,y)$ and then do a sum over $j$, in order to solve the original problem. For example, the gradient and Hessian wrt $W_k$ are the sums
$$\eqalign{
G_k &= \sum_j 2B_k^T(Ax_j-y_j)x_j^TC_k^T \cr
{\mathcal H}_k &= \sum_j 2B_k^TB_k\,{\mathcal E}\,C_k\,x_jx^T_j\,C_k^T \cr
}$$
**Update**

It occurs to me that what I have calculated is
$${\mathcal H_{kk}}=\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial W_k\partial W_k}$$
which is just the "diagonal" part of the full hessian
$${\mathcal H_{ki}}=\frac{\partial G_k}{\partial W_i}=\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial W_k\partial W_i}$$
To calculate the missing components you must consider the $(B_k, C_k)$ terms from $dG_k$, i.e. things like
$$\frac{\partial B_k}{\partial W_i},\,\,\frac{\partial C_k}{\partial W_i}$$ 
It's doable, but tedious.

Comment: This is really really great, thank you! I'm fine leaving the answer as the vectorized hessian (mn x mn). Is $H_k = 2C_kxx^TC_k^T \otimes B_k^TB_k$ the full Hessian? It looks to me like it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the vectorized result, as in the tensor result, I differentiated both times wrt $W_k$, so it's more like the Laplacian than the Hessian. To get the full Hessian when $(i>k)$ then you need to differentiate the $B_k$ term wrt $W_i$, if $(i=k)$ then the $A_k$ term, and if $(i<k)$ then $C_k$. Like I said, it's not difficult, just a bit tedious to keep track of each case.

Comment: I am still studying through this -- is the fact that $H_k$ does not contain any references to $y$ illustrating that it's not the full Hessian?

Comment: Correct. The full Hessian will display $y$ dependence in its off-diagonal terms.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's assume only one layer $y=Wx$ where $W$ is a matrix $m\times n$. Then 
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_{ab}}=2 (Wx- y)_a \,\,x_b$$
(or something like that, I'm omitting the sumation over all cases "$j$"). This can still be represented as an $m\times n$-matrix.

The second deriative, in coordinates, could be something like
$$
\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial W_{ab}\partial W_{cd}}=2\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{cd}} \big((Wx-y)_a \,x_b\big)
=\begin{cases}
2\, x_d \, x_b \quad \text{if}\,\,a=c,\\
0\quad\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Is this what you ask for?